# ActiveMQ Artemis error AMQ224065 explanation?

Tags: activemq-artemis

In ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15.0 version, we are auto-creating queues. As in default auto-delete set to true ( unchanged ). We see following log time to time. From the log message it seems server tries to remove auto-created queue and fails since it has a 1 messages. My question is why broker tries to remove the queue when there are messages in queue ?

```
2020-10-22 02:48:23,599 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224065: Failed to remove auto-created queue test: 
ActiveMQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=AMQ229215: Cannot delete queue test on binding test - it has 1 messages]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can imagine, the broker has lots of threads doing lots of different tasks. It's totally possible for the last message to be removed from the queue and the broker to start the process to delete the queue and in the mean-time another thread adds a message to the queue. This `ERROR` message would be logged in such a situation.

I recommend you disable auto-delete for both addresses and queues or at least set `auto-delete-queues-delay` and `auto-delete-addresses-delay` to a non-zero value (e.g. 5000). Auto deletion will be disabled by default in a future version of the broker.